# Fire Jquery Event on Selection of Dropdown (Not Change of Dropdown Value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a jquery function which i want to fire when dropdown value is selected (not when it is clicked, and not when it is changed - but when any value is selected)

here is the html

```
<select class="addpropertyinput" name="property_availablefor" id="property_availablefor" required>
    <option value="">Available for</option>
    <option value="Rent">Rent</option>
    <option value="Sale">Sale</option>
</select>
<div class="errormsg" id="errormsg3"></div>
```

Jquery

```
var validate_property_availablefor = function()
{
    var item3 = $("#property_availablefor").val();
    $("#errormsg14").html("")
    $("#errormsg21").html("")
    if (item3 == '')
    {
        $("#errormsg3").html("Please Select Available For")
        property_availablefor = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $("#errormsg3").html("")
        property_availablefor = item3;
    }
}

   $("#property_availablefor").on('change', validate_property_availablefor);
```

Now I can replace 'change' with 'click' or 'focusout' but that does not solve problem perfectly, because then it fires as soon as it is clicked or focused out.  I need to fire it when value is selected in dropdown.  Not changed, not when dropdown is clicked.  Only when the dropdown value is selected.

Comment: What is the difference between a value being selected and the value being changed? That seems like the same thing.

Comment: The first value is blank, so if user selects blank then an error message should show, but if value is not changed then no error message is shown, if it is shown on click then the error message flickers, if it shown on focus out then it is a bit late..

Comment: You need to hook your custom function on the "change" event of the select box. Then check the value, and if it's blank, show your error.

Comment: Most developers use the change event on dropdowns, and users kinda know what to expect (like no action if nothing changed). What you are trying to do is create a new kind of user experience, and that's not always a good idea.

Comment: @JakeParis, but i am already checking if the value is blank, and if do it on change then it is not working (maybe because nothing is getting changed), please show me how...

Comment: i can use position: absolute; in css on error message and increase the margin on the elements, but that is changing design....

Comment: i can use 'disabled selected hidden' in html on blank value then the blank value does not show up as a field that can be selected this seems to achieve closes to what i want, even this is creating problems with jquery requiring rewriting of validation function

Answer (score 1):

`<option>` events are not supported on all browsers (I've only confirmed it works on firefox). Keep your current change event, but also add a click event that responds only when the selection is blank:

```js
var validate_property_availablefor = function()
{
    var item3 = $("#property_availablefor").val();
    $("#errormsg14").html("")
    $("#errormsg21").html("")
    if (item3 == '')
    {
        $("#errormsg3").html("Please Select Available For")
        property_availablefor = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $("#errormsg3").html("")
        property_availablefor = item3;
    }
}

$("#property_availablefor").on('change', validate_property_availablefor);

$("#property_availablefor option").on('click', function(event){
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    console.log(selectedVal);
    if (selectedVal === '')//only do something when it's blank
    {
        $("#errormsg3").html("Please Select Available For")
        property_availablefor = "";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="addpropertyinput" name="property_availablefor" id="property_availablefor" required>
    <option value="">Available for</option>
    <option value="Rent">Rent</option>
    <option value="Sale">Sale</option>
</select>
<div class="errormsg" id="errormsg3"></div>
```